# How to do a generic response for akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I need to create a function that evaluates to a Route given a `Future[Either[Error, T]]`
I do it like this

```
def handleFuture[T] handleFuture(f: Future[Either[Error, T]]): Route = {
  onComplete(f) {
    case Failure(er) => complete(InternalServerError, err)
    case Success(Left(er)) => complete(BadRequest, er)
    case Success(Right(value)) => complete(OK, value)
  }
}
```

I have implicit marshallers/unmarshaller in scope for generic type `A` and I get a `too many arguments for method complete` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Change `err` to `er`:

```
case Failure(er) => complete(InternalServerError, er)
                                               // ^
```